# Elasticsearch query speed varies greatly on two nodes with almost the same configuration

Tags: elasticsearch

We have setup two single-node elasticsearch(5.1.1) clusters and indexed almost the same data (about 200G) on them. But when I execute the same query, the speed varies greatly. One is almost twice as fast as the other. Could anybody help me figure out the reason?

Here are some details：
**The query:**

```
GET /trend/_search
{  
   "profile":true,
   "size":0,
   "aggs":{  
      "date_hist_aggr":{  
         "date_histogram":{  
            "field":"publish_time",
            "interval":"day",
            "time_zone":"+08:00"
         }
      }
   },
   "query":{  
      "bool":{  
         "filter":[  
            {  
               "bool":{  
                  "should":[  
                     {  
                        "bool":{  
                           "should":[  
                              {  
                                 "match":{  
                                    "title":{  
                                       "type":"phrase",
                                       "query":"search_text"
                                    }
                                 }
                              },
                              {  
                                 "match":{  
                                    "text":{  
                                       "type":"phrase",
                                       "query":"search_text"
                                    }
                                 }
                              }
                           ],
                           "filter":[  
                              {  
                                 "term":{  
                                    "document_source":{  
                                       "value":"choice_news_full"
                                    }
                                 }
                              }
                           ]
                        }
                     }

                     // more queries ....
                  ]
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

**Profile result of the slower one:**

```
{
  "took": 6990,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 10703,
    "max_score": 0,
    "hits": []
  },
  "profile": {
    "shards": [
      // other shards are similary.
      {
        "id": "[EqbHLX5_SQuKPQ-ZZw7Pmg][trend][1]",
        "searches": [
          {
            "query": [
              {
                "type": "BoostQuery",
                "description": "(ConstantScore((title:\"some_text_to_search\" text:\"some_text_to_search\" #document_source:choice_news_full)~1))^0.0",
                "time": "5132.414299ms",
                "breakdown": {
                  "score": 0,
                  "build_scorer_count": 34,
                  "match_count": 12149,
                  "create_weight": 1506900476,
                  "next_doc": 834988530,
                  "match": 2783243786,
                  "create_weight_count": 1,
                  "next_doc_count": 12181,
                  "score_count": 0,
                  "build_scorer": 7257142,
                  "advance": 0,
                  "advance_count": 0
                },
                "children": [
                  {
                    "type": "BooleanQuery",
                    "description": "(title:\"some_text_to_search\" text:\"some_text_to_search\" #document_source:choice_news_full)~1",
                    "time": "5128.086301ms",
                    "breakdown": {
                      "score": 0,
                      "build_scorer_count": 34,
                      "match_count": 12149,
                      "create_weight": 1506894285,
                      "next_doc": 832868797,
                      "match": 2781145088,
                      "create_weight_count": 1,
                      "next_doc_count": 12181,
                      "score_count": 0,
                      "build_scorer": 7153766,
                      "advance": 0,
                      "advance_count": 0
                    },
                    "children": [
                      {
                        "type": "MultiPhraseQuery",
                        "description": "title:\"some_text_to_search\"",
                        "time": "1123.789370ms",
                        "breakdown": {
                          "score": 0,
                          "build_scorer_count": 34,
                          "match_count": 376,
                          "create_weight": 285785210,
                          "next_doc": 160281857,
                          "match": 673293683,
                          "create_weight_count": 1,
                          "next_doc_count": 402,
                          "score_count": 0,
                          "build_scorer": 3966744,
                          "advance": 460643,
                          "advance_count": 420
                        }
                      },
                      {
                        "type": "MultiPhraseQuery",
                        "description": "text:\"some_text_to_search\"",
                        "time": "3986.896197ms",
                        "breakdown": {
                          "score": 0,
                          "build_scorer_count": 34,
                          "match_count": 11795,
                          "create_weight": 1221076820,
                          "next_doc": 655575011,
                          "match": 2103910865,
                          "create_weight_count": 1,
                          "next_doc_count": 12040,
                          "score_count": 0,
                          "build_scorer": 767627,
                          "advance": 5531401,
                          "advance_count": 10603
                        }
                      },
                      {
                        "type": "TermQuery",
                        "description": "document_source:choice_news_full",
                        "time": "5.050457000ms",
                        "breakdown": {
                          "score": 0,
                          "build_scorer_count": 34,
                          "match_count": 0,
                          "create_weight": 1493,
                          "next_doc": 0,
                          "match": 0,
                          "create_weight_count": 1,
                          "next_doc_count": 0,
                          "score_count": 0,
                          "build_scorer": 233508,
                          "advance": 4792856,
                          "advance_count": 22565
                        }
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                ]
              }
            ],
            "rewrite_time": 22447,
            "collector": [
              {
                "name": "CancellableCollector",
                "reason": "search_cancelled",
                "time": "3.101963000ms",
                "children": [
                  {
                    "name": "MultiCollector",
                    "reason": "search_multi",
                    "time": "2.694232000ms",
                    "children": [
                      {
                        "name": "TotalHitCountCollector",
                        "reason": "search_count",
                        "time": "0.2663410000ms"
                      },
                      {
                        "name": "ProfilingAggregator: [org.elasticsearch.search.profile.aggregation.ProfilingAggregator@70caba80]",
                        "reason": "aggregation",
                        "time": "1.778954000ms"
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        ],
        "aggregations": [
          {
            "type": "org.elasticsearch.search.aggregations.bucket.histogram.DateHistogramAggregator",
            "description": "date_hist_aggr",
            "time": "1.326995000ms",
            "breakdown": {
              "reduce": 0,
              "build_aggregation": 265919,
              "build_aggregation_count": 1,
              "initialize": 4584,
              "initialize_count": 1,
              "reduce_count": 0,
              "collect": 1054442,
              "collect_count": 2048
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

**Profile result of the faster one:**

```
{
  "took": 4622,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 10589,
    "max_score": 0,
    "hits": []
  },
  "profile": {
    "shards": [
      // other shards are similary.
      {
        "id": "[3zJGuDH9TQ-WOLgI2ZKfOA][trend][0]",
        "searches": [
          {
            "query": [
              {
                "type": "BoostQuery",
                "description": "(ConstantScore((title:\"some_text_to_search\" text:\"some_text_to_search\" #document_source:choice_news_full)~1))^0.0",
                "time": "2965.483800ms",
                "breakdown": {
                  "score": 0,
                  "build_scorer_count": 30,
                  "match_count": 11901,
                  "create_weight": 1548877683,
                  "next_doc": 201685172,
                  "match": 1213525903,
                  "create_weight_count": 1,
                  "next_doc_count": 11919,
                  "score_count": 0,
                  "build_scorer": 1371191,
                  "advance": 0,
                  "advance_count": 0
                },
                "children": [
                  {
                    "type": "BooleanQuery",
                    "description": "(title:\"some_text_to_search\" text:\"some_text_to_search\" #document_source:choice_news_full)~1",
                    "time": "2961.314893ms",
                    "breakdown": {
                      "score": 0,
                      "build_scorer_count": 30,
                      "match_count": 11901,
                      "create_weight": 1548873529,
                      "next_doc": 199676450,
                      "match": 1211468384,
                      "create_weight_count": 1,
                      "next_doc_count": 11919,
                      "score_count": 0,
                      "build_scorer": 1272679,
                      "advance": 0,
                      "advance_count": 0
                    },
                    "children": [
                      {
                        "type": "MultiPhraseQuery",
                        "description": "title:\"some_text_to_search\"",
                        "time": "377.6214820ms",
                        "breakdown": {
                          "score": 0,
                          "build_scorer_count": 30,
                          "match_count": 443,
                          "create_weight": 357702051,
                          "next_doc": 9996950,
                          "match": 9403763,
                          "create_weight_count": 1,
                          "next_doc_count": 461,
                          "score_count": 0,
                          "build_scorer": 502110,
                          "advance": 15670,
                          "advance_count": 3
                        }
                      },
                      {
                        "type": "MultiPhraseQuery",
                        "description": "text:\"some_text_to_search\"",
                        "time": "2573.946724ms",
                        "breakdown": {
                          "score": 0,
                          "build_scorer_count": 30,
                          "match_count": 11486,
                          "create_weight": 1191134981,
                          "next_doc": 183139344,
                          "match": 1199396032,
                          "create_weight_count": 1,
                          "next_doc_count": 11747,
                          "score_count": 0,
                          "build_scorer": 196634,
                          "advance": 56460,
                          "advance_count": 9
                        }
                      },
                      {
                        "type": "TermQuery",
                        "description": "document_source:choice_news_full",
                        "time": "3.243158000ms",
                        "breakdown": {
                          "score": 0,
                          "build_scorer_count": 30,
                          "match_count": 0,
                          "create_weight": 1382,
                          "next_doc": 0,
                          "match": 0,
                          "create_weight_count": 1,
                          "next_doc_count": 0,
                          "score_count": 0,
                          "build_scorer": 211093,
                          "advance": 3018723,
                          "advance_count": 11929
                        }
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                ]
              }
            ],
            "rewrite_time": 10115,
            "collector": [
              {
                "name": "CancellableCollector",
                "reason": "search_cancelled",
                "time": "2.942374000ms",
                "children": [
                  {
                    "name": "MultiCollector",
                    "reason": "search_multi",
                    "time": "2.540610000ms",
                    "children": [
                      {
                        "name": "TotalHitCountCollector",
                        "reason": "search_count",
                        "time": "0.2359210000ms"
                      },
                      {
                        "name": "ProfilingAggregator: [org.elasticsearch.search.profile.aggregation.ProfilingAggregator@63c09142]",
                        "reason": "aggregation",
                        "time": "1.663939000ms"
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        ],
        "aggregations": [
          {
            "type": "org.elasticsearch.search.aggregations.bucket.histogram.DateHistogramAggregator",
            "description": "date_hist_aggr",
            "time": "1.451517000ms",
            "breakdown": {
              "reduce": 0,
              "build_aggregation": 288404,
              "build_aggregation_count": 1,
              "initialize": 1827,
              "initialize_count": 1,
              "reduce_count": 0,
              "collect": 1159177,
              "collect_count": 2107
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
```

Comment: Could you share your configuration? Because what you see as "almost" the same settings might have a dramatic impact. Also if I understand correctly, you have 2 single ES nodes, they are not communicating with each other right?

Comment: Yes, they are seperated as the cluster.names are different. Default values are used for other configurations. Only the hardwares are different: 
the faster one: 8G RAM, 500G HDD;
the slower one: 16G RAM, 1T HDD.

Comment: And do you use mappings when inserting data into ES?

Comment: Yes, I specified the same mapping explicitly before index any data.

Comment: In that kind of case, I'd look at the I/O, CPU, memory statistics first of all

Answer (score 0):

I got it!

The faster node has run for a long time, and we have performed many queries on it, so it's well warmed-up. After executing a script that queries many phrases, the slower node became more faster now.

@asettouf, Thanks for your advices!